# HTML/CSS Items are placed under eachother - Need to be scrollable

Tags: html, css

I have a box with items which are working fine with a couple of items, but if it exceed x amount of items the next item goes under the other - [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XH4a4.png).
The 8th item need to go beside the 7th and then the box needs to be scrollable.

Code:

```
<ul class="items">
 <div class="box">
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
<li>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/class/730/1026951730/128fx100f">
        <h5>Test</h5>
        <p class="price">$25.00</p>
    </a>
</li>
</div>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul.items li {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    *display: inline;
}
p.price {
    color: #A65353;
}
box {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
box {
background: #fff;
border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
padding-bottom: 5px;
margin-top: 5px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-x: scroll
}
```

Comment: @KeithA That did not help.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow-x: scroll`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set like this

**CSS**

```
ul.items li {
    width: 150px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    *display: inline;
}
p.price {
    color: #A65353;
}
box {
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    // add this styles
    white-space:no-wrap;
    overflow-x:scroll;
}
```